# Computed property setter is not being invoked

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, quasar

So I have a computed property which is an object of a type which I have defined in my Vuex Store. I'm trying to use this property on my component with v-model. I have defined getters and setters for this property and I'm pretty sure I have configured everything correctly unless I have overlooked something. I tried console logging inside of the setter to see if it ever fires up but nothing gets logged in the console so it isn't being called at all. Any help would be appreciated

code for Store:

```
import { Module, VuexModule, getModule, Mutation, Action } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import { websocket } from 'src/boot/socket.io-client'
import store from 'src/store'
import { DataTablePagination } from '../types'
import { Course } from './types'
import { MessageModule } from 'src/store/message/index'
import { Notify } from 'quasar'
import { validate } from "class-validator"

export { Course } from './types'
export { DataTablePagination } from '../types'
export interface CourseState {
  pagination: DataTablePagination
  courses: Course []
  filter: string,
  disabled: boolean,
  selected: Course [],
  active: boolean,
  editCourseOpened: boolean,
  addCourseOpened: boolean,
  addCourseData: Course,
  editCourseData: Course,
  addCourseDisabled: boolean
}

@Module({
  name: 'course',
  namespaced: true,
  dynamic: true,
  store
})

class CourseClass extends VuexModule implements CourseState {
  public pagination: DataTablePagination = {
    descending: false,
    rowsNumber: 0,
    rowsPerPage: 10,
    page: 1,
    sortBy: 'name'
  }
  public courses: Course [] = []
  public filter = ''
  public disabled = true
  public selected: Course [] = []
  public active = true
  public editCourseOpened = false
  public addCourseOpened = false
  public addCourseData = new Course()
  public editCourseData = new Course()
  public addCourseDisabled = true

  @Mutation
  SET_ADDCOURSEDISABLED(disabled: boolean) {
    this.addCourseDisabled=disabled
  }

  @Mutation
  SET_EDITCOURSEDATA(data: Course) {
    this.editCourseData.copy(data)
  }

  // public SET_ADDCOURSEDATA(payload: { key: string, value: number | string }) {
  //   const { key, value } = payload
  //   if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, key)) {
  //     // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  //     (this as any)[key] = value
  //   }
  // }
  @Mutation
  SET_ADDCOURSEDATA(data: Course) {
    this.addCourseData.copy(data)
  }

  @Mutation
  SET_EDITCOURSEOPENED(opened: boolean) {
    this.editCourseOpened=opened
  } 

  @Mutation
  SET_ADDCOURSEOPENED(opened: boolean) {
    this.addCourseOpened=opened
  }

  @Mutation
  SET_ACTIVE(active: boolean) {
    this.active=active
  }

  @Mutation
  SET_PAGINATION(pagination: DataTablePagination) {
    this.pagination=pagination
  }

  @Mutation
  SET_SELECTED(selected: Course []) {
    this.selected=selected
  }

  @Mutation
  SET_FILTER(filter: string) {
    this.filter=filter
  }

  @Mutation
  SET_COURSES(courses: Course []) {
    this.courses=courses
  }

  @Mutation
  SET_DISABLED(disabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled=disabled
  }

  @Action
  public ValidateAddCourseData() {
    validate(this.addCourseDisabled).then(errors => {
      console.log(errors)
      if(errors.length) {
        this.SET_ADDCOURSEDISABLED(true)
      } else {
        this.SET_ADDCOURSEDISABLED(false)
      }
    })
  }

  @Action 
  public async addCourse(input: Course) {
    websocket.emit('query', `mutation {
      createCourse (
        course: {
          code: "${input.code}"
          name: "${input.name}"
          creditHours: ${input.creditHours}
          numberOfLabs: ${input.numberOfLabs}
          contactHours: ${input.contactHours}
          chargeableCredits: 0
        }
      ) {
        ok
        message
      }
  }`, (response: { 
    errors: any
    data: { 
      createAcademicProgram: { 
        ok: boolean
        message: String 
      } 
    } 
  }) => {
      if(response.data) {
        this.fetchCourses()
        Notify.create({
          timeout: 3000,
          position: 'center',
          color: 'primary',
          message: 'Course Added Successfully'
        })
        this.SET_ADDCOURSEOPENED(!this.addCourseOpened)
      }
      else {
        MessageModule.newMessage({title: 'Error: Addition Failed', icon: 'error', message: 'Addition failed. Ensure that the course code you have entered is unique or contact your system administrator'})
      }
    })
  }

  @Action 
  public async deleteCourse(input: Course) {
    websocket.emit('query', `mutation {
      deleteCourse (
        courseId: "${input.id}"
      )  {
        id
        ok
        message
      }
    }`, (response: { 
      errors: any; 
      data: { 
        deleteCourse: { 
          id: any; 
          ok: boolean; 
          message: String 
        } 
      } 
    }) => {
      if(response.data) {
        this.fetchCourses()
        Notify.create({
          timeout: 2000,
          position: 'center',
          color: 'primary',
          message: 'Course Deleted Successfully'
        })
      }
      else {
        MessageModule.newMessage({ title: 'Deletion Failed', icon: 'error', message: 'Deletion Failed. Ensure that no course instances are still tied to this course or contact your system administrator' })
      }
    })
  }

  @Action
  public async editCourse(input: Course) {
    websocket.emit('query', `mutation {
      updateCourse (
        course: {
          id: "${input.id}"
          code: "${input.code}"
          name: "${input.name}"
          creditHours: ${input.creditHours}
          numberOfLabs: ${input.numberOfLabs}
          contactHours: ${input.contactHours}
          chargeableCredits: 0
        }
      ) {
        id
        ok
        message
      }
    }`, (response: {
      errors: any
      data: {
        updateCourse: {
          id: string
          ok: boolean
          message: string
        }
      }
    }) => {
      if(response.data) {
        this.fetchCourses()
        this.SET_SELECTED([input])
        this.SET_EDITCOURSEOPENED(!this.editCourseOpened)
        Notify.create({
          timeout: 3000,
          color: 'primary',
          message: 'Course Updated Successfully',
          position: 'center'
        })
      }
      else {
        MessageModule.newMessage({ title: 'Update Failed', icon: 'error', message: 'Update Failed. Ensure that all course codes are unique or contact your system administrator'})
      }
    })
  }

  @Action 
  public async fetchCourses() {
    const order = this.pagination.sortBy !== null ? `order: {
      by: ${this.pagination.sortBy}
      dir: ${this.pagination.descending ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'}
    }` : ''
    websocket.emit('query', `{
      courses(
        page: {
          skip: ${(this.pagination.page - 1) * this.pagination.rowsPerPage},
          first: ${this.pagination.rowsPerPage}
        }
        filter: {
          ilike: {
            name: "${this.filter}"
          }
        }
        ${order}
      ) {
        pagination {
          total
          listTotal
        }
        list {
          id
          code
          name
          creditHours
          numberOfLabs
          contactHours
        }
      }
    }`, (response: {
      errors: any
      data: {
        courses: {
          list: Course[]
          pagination: {
            total: number
            listTotal: number
          }
        }
      }
    }) => {
      this.SET_COURSES(response.data.courses.list)
      this.pagination.rowsNumber = response.data.courses.pagination.total
    })
  }
}

export const CourseModule = getModule(CourseClass)
```

Code for component:

```
<template>
  <q-dialog v-model="isOpened" :bordered="true">
    <q-card style="width: 50vw;">
      <q-toolbar class="bg-grey-5 text-center">
        <q-toolbar-title>Add Course</q-toolbar-title>
        <q-btn flat round dense icon="close" v-close-popup />
      </q-toolbar>
      <q-card-section class="col">
        <q-input v-model.trim="course.name" label="Name" type="object"
        :rules="[
          val => val.length > 0 || 'Required field'
        ]"/>
        <q-input v-model="course.code" label="Code"
        :rules="[
          val => val.length > 0 || 'Required field'
        ]"/>
        <q-input v-model.number="course.creditHours" label="Credit Hours" type="number"
        :rules="[
          val => val >= 0 || 'No negatives allowed'
        ]"/>
        <q-input v-model.number="course.numberOfLabs" label="Number of Labs" type="number"
        :rules="[
          val => val >= 0 || 'No negatives allowed'
        ]"/>
        <q-input v-model.number="course.contactHours" label="Contact Hours" type="number"
        :rules="[
          val => val >= 0 || 'No negatives allowed'
        ]"/>
        <q-card-actions align="right">
          <q-btn color="primary" :disable="disabled" @click="submit();">
            <q-icon name="save" />
            <q-tooltip
              anchor="top middle"
              self="bottom middle"
              :offset="[10, 10]"
            >
              <strong>Add Course</strong>
            </q-tooltip>
          </q-btn>
          <q-btn color="red" @click="toggle()" icon="cancel">
            <q-tooltip
            anchor="top middle"
            self="bottom middle"
            :offset="[10, 10]"
            >
              <strong>Cancel</strong>
            </q-tooltip>
          </q-btn>
        </q-card-actions>
      </q-card-section>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { CourseModule, Course } from 'src/store/course/index'

@Component
export default class AddCourse extends Vue {
  //private course: Course = new Course()
  //private disabled = true

  get disabled() {
    return CourseModule.addCourseDisabled
  }

  get course() {
    return CourseModule.addCourseData
  }

  set course(args: any) {
    console.log(args)
    //CourseModule.SET_ADDCOURSEDATA(newValue)
  }

  get isOpened() {
    return CourseModule.addCourseOpened
  }

  set isOpened(newValue: boolean) {
    CourseModule.SET_ADDCOURSEOPENED(newValue)
  }

  toggle() {
    CourseModule.SET_ADDCOURSEDATA(this.course)
    this.isOpened = !this.isOpened
    // if(this.isOpened) {
    //   this.getdisabled()
    // }
    // else {
    //   this.course.clear()
    // }
  }

  submit() {
    CourseModule.addCourse(this.course)
    //this.toggle()
  }

  // getdisabled() {
  //   validate(this.course).then(errors => {
  //     if(errors.length) {
  //       this.disabled=true
  //     } else {
  //       this.disabled=false
  //     }
  //   })
  //   return true
  // }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that attempts to write a new value to the `course` property. Using `v-model.trim="course.name"` doesn't set the value of `course`, it sets the value of `name` within the `course` object. The object referenced by `course` will still be the same object, so there's no call to `set`.

Comment: I had commented out the line of code that writes the new value for testing purposes. I found this forum which seems to explain my predicament. https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-v-model-on-property-in-nested-object/6242

Comment: However, the solution they have is to create different getters and setters for each field within the object which is not a very streamlined solution in my opinion. Is there any way to have just one setter and getter and have it working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already noted, the standard solution here would be to have a computed property for each form field, with `get` and `set` for each one passing through to the store.

One viable alternative would be to use a `Proxy` to intercept the setting of the object properties. I don't know how to write this in TypeScript but that shouldn't detract from the core idea:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    course: {
      name: 'Algebra',
      teacher: 'Smith'
    }
  },
  
  mutations: {
    course (state, course) {
      state.course = course
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  
  computed: {
    course () {
      const store = this.$store
      const course = store.state.course
      
      return new Proxy(course, {
        set (obj, key, value) {
          store.commit('course', { ...obj, [key]: value })          
          return true
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="course.name">
  <br>
  <input v-model="course.teacher">
  <br>
  <p>{{ course.name }}</p>
  <p>{{ course.teacher }}</p>
</div>
```

If you need to support IE then you won't be able to use `Proxy` but it should be possible to implement something similar using standard JavaScript properties. The idea is much the same as for the proper `Proxy` but you'd have to explicitly create `get` and `set` handlers on the 'proxy' object.

Comment: I went ahead and got around my issue by simply having the Course object on the component itself instead of on the store. Thanks a lot though for the quick response. I'll go ahead and accept the answer. Maybe I can use it for future purposes